# Load .json file data to Postgres for Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, import, postgresql-9.4

The terminal objective is to have 1.6 million records ingested into Postgres for discovery in my Rails 5 API app. I have 45 .json files each containing an array of json objects. Each file has between between 2k to 30k objects each. The file sizes range from 6MB to 188MB. I tried to use the seed.db file and read the files in that way but the memory utilization was too high. I then used the yajl gem to treat the files as streams but in larger files, I would get a network error after a while as the process for writing each object would take up to an hour.

Is there a more efficient way, memory-wise, to handle ingesting large files through seed.db or some other mechanism within Rails itself?

Is there a tool specific to handling ingestion of json files with an array of objects into Postgres? I see pgfutter but I can't get that tool to initialize on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, you can use seeds.rb, or a migration, or a few different ways. Can you provide more details about the structure of your json data files and how they relate to the models in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using Sqlize to convert the json files to a SQL query. Easy from there.